# Oracle SQL Output to Excel - Date format issue

Tags: oracle, excel, vba

I ran an SQL Query for Oracle which consists of Invoice date and Check date. When these data are copied on to an Excel Spreadsheet as text, it's dispayed as ex: "13-10-31" (Oct 31, 2013). However, when converted to date format, it's displayed as "10/13/1931". I've tried different date types but it always recognizes as the first part of the text as the day, then month, then year. I need these values to be setup as a date format as I need to calculate Days Payable Outstanding and other related ratios.

Is there any way to convert these values so that Excel recognizes the day, month, and year correctly? Would there be a macro that could automate this process for existing data and data that will be added in the future?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try _to_Char(urdate,'MM/DD/YYYY')_ instead of depending on implicit date format in output.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I hope the data type of your date column is `DATE`.
Secondly, the date should always have year as `YYYY` and not just `YY`. The world has already learned from Y2K bug.

If above two points are met, then while displaying use `to_char(date_column, 'mm/dd/yyyy')`. Thus, with `YYYY` format, there won't be any confusion between year and other fields.